# Django: 'NOT NULL constraint failed' when implementing comment functionality

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a model named Thoughts which has many Comments, so I defined a Comment section with a primary key to Thoughts.

```
from django.db import models

class Thoughts(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    thought = models.CharField(max_length=500)

class Comments(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    original_post = models.ForeignKey(Thoughts)
```

Here's my forms.py which defines a field for commenting:

```
class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    comment = forms.CharField(max_length=500)

    class Meta:
        model = Comments
        fields = ('name','comment',)
```

The view for handling the form data:

```
def thought(request, thought_num):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            c =Comments.objects.create(name=form.cleaned_data['name'],
                comment=form.cleaned_data['comment'])
            c.save()
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'thought.html', {'form': form})
```

When I try to enter the values in the form, I get this error:

```
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
NOT NULL constraint failed: thoughts_comments.original_post_id
```

I suspect it has to do with these lines:

```
        c = Comments.objects.create(name=form.cleaned_data['name'],
            comment=form.cleaned_data['comment'])
        c.save()
```

the post data goes through fine without those lines(just wont create the comment), so something with the model maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not passing `original_post` when creating `Comments` object, the error is raised as database is expecting non-null value for `original_post`.

You need to add `blank` and `null` arguments to `original_post` field in `Comments` model. This will allow `Foreignkey` field `original_post` to have null values.

```
original_post = models.ForeignKey(Thoughts, blank=True, null=True)
```

After adding these arguments, you will need to run migrations.

Comment: Did you do `migrate`?

Comment: Nope! It works now, comments are showing up in localhost/admin. Any reason why these fields are necessary, out of curiosity.

Comment: Database expects a non-nullable value for a field unless `null=True` is not specified in the model field. It will enforce that constraint. If you don't pass in the value, it will raise an error. Also check this [docs link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#null)